# How can I call a page when i clicked the button in codeiginiter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not calling a page in codeiginiter when i click button..

i am new in this so please HELP....

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o nav_icon"></i>Forms<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('application/views/middlepage/inputs.php'); ?>">Inputs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('application/views/middlepage/validation.php'); ?>">Form Validation</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

on theme implement in codeiginiter i can't call the page 
it's is show the page was not found but i given correct path on it.

Comment: you can use a contorller->function to load `view`

Comment: but it can call all pages

Comment: You have to use <?php echo base_url('controller_name/function_name') ?> so that it will print desired page url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to understand MVC Architecture..

You just have to call Controller/Method where you call your view.
example:

Controller

```
<?php

class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller{
   public function orders(){
     $this->load->view('orderpage');
   }
}

?>
```

view - Orderpage.php

```
<body>
<h3>orders list</h3>
</body>
```

your just have to add anchor tag like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('mycontroller/orders');?>">Go to orders</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Both of You for giving Reply. It really works

Answer (score 0):

> Edit config/config.php file

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/codeigniter/';`

> in view

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('Controller_name/function_name'); ?>">Inputs</a>`

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup routs for View
go to

> \application\config\routes.php

and add a route at the end like this

```
$route['ViewName'] = 'ViewPath';
```

My views are presented in

> application\views\user

so i will add

```
$route['confirm'] = 'user/confirm';
```